# Descriptions on tenses

Tags: vocabulary

Under what linguistic category do `Simple`, `Perfect`, `Continuous`, and Perfect Continuous fall ?

Past Simple
Past Perfect
Past Continuous
Past Perfect Continuous
Past Subjunctive

Comment: Please don't post the same question with slightly different wording.

Comment: People are in the habit of closing posts without good reason.  Becoming a big problem.

Comment: You're asking two different questions here: (1) where to find information, and (2) linguistic categories. Two questions in one makes your question off-topic. Requests for resources are also off-topic on ELL, but *on-topic* at [meta]. I've edited your first question out.